# SFML window application remove console

Tags: c++, sfml

For an application, while I make the final application, How could I remove the terminal window for the final application on MacOS or Linux.
[image]

Comment: You should spend some time reading the SFML FAQ (https://www.sfml-dev.org/faq.php#tr-win-console) and the tutorials, etc. This is all documented.

Comment: Yeah,it's on windows, but not on macos and linux.I need a solution on macos or linux.

Comment: On Linux you'll have a console if you start the application from one (obviously), if you start it from a IDE it will usually also open a console (for convenience), but if you start the application from a GUI like KDE or Gnome then they won't automatically open a console window. So your question seems a bit moot.

Answer (score 0):

I find the key point, that is in macos we should build a app file, which should consist of Resources folder、MACOS、PkgInfo、Info.plist files, then when  I just click the packaged file, the application could just show the GUI window.